# A word for "without getting your hands dirty"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, antonyms

Consider an entrepreneur who builds a business through personal effort. This might be called sweat equity or getting your hands dirty.

What is a concise phrase, preferably a single word, which represents the opposite?

As requested, here's an example of how the word I imagine might be used in context:

*By leveraging prototyping-as-a-service, manufacturing-as-a-service, and fulfillment-as-service, Jim was able to build an end-to-end business without ever getting his hands dirty. He called this approach **[WORD]** production.*

Comment: Well, if it involves theft, or at least questionable means, the term is "scott free".

Comment: If there was little or no direct involvement then his role or participation was *hands off*.

Comment: Building a business through your own effort is not what "sweat equity" means.  However what you're looking for might be manager, overseer, possibly absent landlord (although that has negative connotation).  I doubt you can handle this in one word--it took you two sentences to describe the opposite.

Comment: Drew I think you've come the closest so far. Add that suggestion as an answer and if I see nothing better I'll accept it.

Comment: "Other people's money" or "other people's labor" go to not getting your hands dirty.

Comment: Did he somehow build a business with little effort of any kind? If so he seems highly efficient,  or very lucky.  Was he necessarily manipulative and exploitative, or are his staff, customers and suppliers all treated fairly?  Or are you thinking more of someone who, for example, puts a lot of effort into organising a plumbing business: advertising,  recruiting, training, monitoring, negotiating with suppliers etc., but never actually mends a tap?

Comment: You need to define what you mean a little more clearly, and include a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. Right now, it's not clear whether you want to talk about someone who built a business using *other people's physical labor* or just someone whose business is *not physical* or something else entirely.

Comment: I added an example of the context in which the word could be used to drive the point home as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A neutral noun is **silent partner**:

> *Silent partner*: a partner in a business who has no control over how the business is managed - [Macmillan Dictionary - American English definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/silent-partner)

For adjectives, **arm's length** or **long-distance**:

> *Arm's length*: a distance sufficient to exclude intimacy - [Based on WordNet 3.0](http://www.freethesaurus.com/arm%27s+length)
>
> *Long-distance*: of, from, or between distant places - [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/long-distance)

Comment: Excellent word for the entrepreneur (noun), but I am looking for a term about his activity (verb). The silent partner does what? Take a look at the question where I now added an example paragraph for context.

Comment: Do you want _arm's length_? The example seems to call for an adjective, maybe _long-distance_, _repackaged_, or your own word, _leveraged_.

Comment: ah right. I need an adjective that's true. Yes I think arm's length or long-distance would be suitable. Add that to your answer and if I see no better answer I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could say the individual built the business through **unscrupulous means**.

> **[Unscrupulous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unscrupulous)**: Unscrupulous, unprincipled refer to lack of moral standards or conscience to guide one's conduct. The unscrupulous person is without scruples of conscience, and disregards, or has contempt for, laws of right or justice with which he or she is perfectly well acquainted, and which should restrain his or her actions: unscrupulous in methods of making money, in taking advantage of the unfortunate.

While it may seem extreme for characterizing one who's merely built a business without much personal effort, it's an appropriate term that's commonly used to describe dishonest behavior.

If, however, you're looking for a term to describe one who's merely had everything handed to them instead of having to work for it, or someone who's gotten away, as @Hot Licks mentions, scott-free, you could say they're **[privileged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/privileged)**.

> The privileged businessman barely exerted any effort in building his empire.

Comment: I don't intend unethical means. I do intend something like privileged, but I'd like a more neutral term if possible. Or even one with a positive connotation.

I also considered 'white-glove' and 'handsfree' along these lines.

Comment: Downvoter, care to elaborate?